# Как исправить ошибку в дискорд боте, при воспроизведении яндекс музыки

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, discord, ffmpeg

Я нашел [дискорд бота для воспроизведении треков с Яндекс Музыки](https://github.com/Delitel-WEB/YandexMusicDiscordBot). Сделал всё по инструкции, но при попытке начать проигрывание трека, вылазит такая ошибка:

```
C:\***\***\***\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

Хотя `ffprobe` размещен в пути. Заранее спасибо за помощь, а то уже совсем отчаялся.

Answer (score 0):

У вас отсутствует ffmpeg, либо вы не указали к нему путь либо указали, но неверно (отладка в помощь).
Смотрите **"Необходимые зависимости"** на странице проекта с GitHub